# How to filter a certain object property value with angular select box

Tags: angularjs

I would like to filter out a object that has a property value of `"None"`. The object `CounterParty` has 2 properties, `CounterPartyId` and `CounterPartyName`.

The first object in the db has `CounterPartyName: "None"`, I do not want this to show in the select box options.

I setup a plunker but the select-box is not working and there are no errors in the console:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4i6zO4yqCeLq0bRMUD8?p=preview)

```
  <select ng-model="search.CounterParty" 
          ng-options="c.CounterPartyName as c.CounterPartyName for c in counterPsList | unique: 'CounterPartyName'">
   {{c.CounterParty}}
 </select>
```

Json

```
$scope.counterParties = [
  {"$id":"1","CounterPartyId":1,"CounterPartyName":"None","Documents":null},
  {"$id":"2","CounterPartyId":2,"CounterPartyName":"CounterParty A","Documents":null},
  {"$id":"3","CounterPartyId":3,"CounterPartyName":"Counter Party B","Documents":null},
  {"$id":"4","CounterPartyId":4,"CounterPartyName":"Counter Party C","Documents":null},
  {"$id":"5","CounterPartyId":5,"CounterPartyName":"Counter Party D","Documents":null}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use angular-ui's `unique` filter here - its purpose is something else.

If you just need to filter out based on a certain property, you could specify the filter expression like so (notice the `!`):

```
ng-options = '...in counterPsList | filter: { CounterPartyName: "!None" }'
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMzGboRrY1TkMvoKrlah?p=preview)